# compound If then Logic for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I have two index webpages with separate detail pages on a single domain.

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/index.php
```

which yields:

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/detail.php?kfld=address-city-state-zip,
```

and

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/LandContractIndex.php
```

which yields

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/LandContractsDetail.php?kfld=address-city-state-zip.
```

After modifying the .htaccess page as follows:

```
options -multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]    
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I am able to get the following desired results:

```
 www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/address-city-state-zip.html
```

Which leads me to believe that in order to get

the same output:

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/address-city-state-zip.html
```

for input:

```
www.mymichiganforeclosures.com/LandContractsDetail.php?kfld=address-city-state-zip
```

I need to use a compound rewrite code block in my .htaccess, ala:

```
 options -multiviews
 RewriteEngine On

 if foreclosures
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]  
 else
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+LandContractsDetail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /LandContractsDetail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
 endif
```

OR I need to figure out how to pass a complete wildcard for detail and LandContractDetail (optimal).

Any suggestions as the following doesn't work either:

```
 options -multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+detail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /detail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+LandContractDetail\.php\?kfld=([^\s&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /LandContractDetail.php?kfld=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What exactly should be `if foreclosures` condition? Both URIs have `www.mymichiganforeclosures.com` domain right?

Comment: Yes, both use the same domains.  Though LandContractsIndex can also be called directly by typing in www.landcontractlist.com for the URL.

Comment: So again the question remains that `What exactly should be if foreclosures condition?` in your pseudo code above?

Comment: current page = detail for foreclosures or current page = landcontractdetail.com for land contract

Comment: SO it should be based on domain `landcontractdetail.com` vs `mymichiganforeclosures.com` ?

Comment: We need the domain www.mymichiganforeclosures.com to work as is.  It is the primary domain.  www.landcontractsList.com is a simply a redirect.